# can not display quantity_and_stock_status attribute in layered navigation in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter

I have tried to set `quantity_and_stock_status` attribute to make filterable on the product list page. I have set it from the admin panel(**Stores -> Attributes -> Product**) but I can not see a stock filter on the front end. What could be the issue? Please provide a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> quantity_and_stock_status

is the attribute code name is

> Quantity

When changing the settings I have found a bug,it didn't save and showed the loading image,

It was a magento 2 bug same as https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8202 ,

> for a quick solution you can do is inspect the options and remove the
>   disabled attribute and then save.

It worked for me.

Comment: I have upgraded magento to latest version 2.2.4 and issue fixed.

Comment: yes, latest versions fixed the lot of bugs

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

As I have a specific function to update inventory that extends \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry, I called inside it, but if you use Magento itself you should create a plugin to be called after you have run the function **Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry::updateStockItemBySku()**. At each inventory update, this function updates the **is_in_stock** status of the parent product by adding the items of the child products:

`

```
public function syncProductStock(int $productId)
{
    $product = $this->productFactory->create();
    $product->load($productId);

    $productParent= $this->productFactory->create();
    $productParent->load(
        $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable::class)
            ->getParentIdsByChild($productId)
    );

    $childrenIds = array_values(
        $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable::class)
            ->getChildrenIds($productParent->getId())[0]
    );
    $sumQuantity = 0;
    foreach ($childrenIds as $childrenId) {
        $productChildren = $this->productFactory->create();
        $productChildren->load($childrenId);
        $sumQuantity += $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry::class)
            ->getStockItem($childrenId)->getQty();
    }

    $isInStock = $sumQuantity > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $product->addAttributeUpdate('quantity_and_stock_status', $this->getStockItem($productId)->getIsInStock(), $product->getStoreId());
    $productParent->addAttributeUpdate('quantity_and_stock_status', $isInStock, $product->getStoreId());

    $parentStockItem = $this->getStockItem($productParent->getId());
    $parentStockItem->setIsInStock($isInStock);
    $this->stockItemRepository->save($parentStockItem);
}`
```

Hope this helps! Thank you!